# What does this DB error mean? (in AMember with VBulletin)

Tags: php, mysql

> Vbulletin3 plugin error: DB - [] - incorrect value. Error: Table 'my_db.user' doesn't exist

(where "my_db" is the name of my database).

I'm trying to integrate VBulletin with AMember Pro.
I've bought licenses for both. Each has their MySQL
database and user (with full privileges).  Each has
the integration plugin for the other.

But when I go into AMember, I see that error. And
when I try to populate fields in the VBulletin plugin,
I get the error.

Can't find the answer on the support sites.  Need a
programmer!

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It means that either `my_db` doesn't exist or the table `user` is not created within the database.